# Redirect link when option correct

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create some sort of hack challenge. My idea is based on modify the code. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class='info description'>
        Login as Ronald to complete the level
</div>

<div class='level-form'>
    <form method="POST" action="../Ronald.php">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="user">Username:</label>
            <select id="user" name="user">
                <option>John</option>
                <option>Petter</option>
                <option>David</option>
                <option>Sam</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
        </fieldset>
    </form>           
</div>
```

I want to redirect to a next page, only after they modify one option to Ronald.

What do I need to put in the PHP file?

Comment: Do you mean an auto-redirect happens if one of the options becomes Ronald and is selected by the user? You'd have to use Javascript.

Comment: That would be even harder for me, cause i'm new in JavaScript. And also, i do not want that user see the link (cause if he can see the link, he can pass it without resolving it.)

Comment: open developer tools and edit the option

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. But i want to make the question. I don't know if u understand me. I mean...I want to make this challenge.

Comment: Until this moment, with my knowledge about php, i got this:........<?php
echo $_REQUEST['user'];
if ($_REQUEST!='Ronald')  return false;{
 else  header( 'Location: http://192.168.1.22/reto/reto-ftp.html' ) ; }
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working!

Just change the http://yourdomain.com/successPage.php to the url you require.
In order to pass test, change value of any options to Ronald, select that option and submit.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {

if ($_POST['user'] == "Ronald") {
    print "You did it... Moving on <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=http://yourdomain.com/successPage.php'>";

} else {
    print "Sorry... Try again <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."'>";

}

} else { 
?>

<div class='info description'>
        Login as Ronald to complete the level
</div>

<div class='level-form'>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="user">Username:</label>
        <select id="user" name="user">
            <option value="John">John</option>
            <option value="Petter">Petter</option>
            <option value="David">David</option>
            <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
    </fieldset>
</form>           
</div>

<?php } ?>
```